# Problema con la manipulación del DOM en JavaScript al intentar cambiar dinámicamente el contenido de un elemento HTML

Tags: javascript

Estoy enfrentando un problema al intentar cambiar dinámicamente el contenido de un elemento HTML utilizando JavaScript. La idea es que el contenido del elemento se actualice según ciertos eventos en mi aplicación, pero no estoy obteniendo el resultado esperado.

He intentado varias aproximaciones, incluyendo el uso de innerHTML y textContent, pero aún así, no logro que el cambio se refleje en la interfaz de usuario. ¿Alguien podría orientarme sobre cuál podría ser el problema o darme alguna sugerencia para abordar este escenario?

```html
//Código JavaScript relevante a mi problema
const elemento = document.getElementById('miElemento');
const nuevoContenido = "Nuevo contenido dinámico";

// Intento cambiar el contenido del elemento
// (pero no está funcionando como esperaba)
elemento.innerHTML = nuevoContenido;
```

Soy relativamente nuevo en JavaScript y la manipulación del DOM, así que cualquier orientación o sugerencia será de gran ayuda. ¡Gracias de antemano por su tiempo y ayuda amable comunidad de Stack Overflow!

Comment: Hola. No queda claro en tu código qué evento debe ocurrir para que el cambio ocurra: clic de un botón, carga de la página, selección de un elemento,  etc.

Comment: Ese código funciona perfecto cuando agregas el html necesario `<div id="miElemento"></div>`